# How to filter to show largest row value in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I did this once before but can't remember how to now but I know it's possible.  I have a pivot table with two rows and a sum value in classic pivot table layout.  How do I show the largest value based off of the first row.  For instance, first row is A rated bonds and within that category, there could be 50 issuers and then the sum of the market value for each issuer.  I would like to show the pivot table that shows the largest issuer for each rating.

Comment: So first row is rating, second row is Issuer and then sum of market value for each issuer

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the Issuer column of the pivot table, select Filter > Top 10 and in the next dialog enter a 1 for top 1.

[image]

[image]